# Differens between page["propertyName"] and page.property["propertyName"] in EPiServer?

Tags: .net, episerver

What is the difference between accessing a property through page["propertyName"] and page.Property["propertyName"] in EPiServer?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page["PropName"] uses the indexer of the PageData class to return the Value of the PropertyData object.

page.Property["PropName"] will return the whole PropertyData object (for example a PropertyLongString)

so page["PropName"] equals page.Property["PropName"].Value

Comment: Are you sure that page["PropName"] == page.Property["PropName"]= The first returns an object, the latter a PropertyData object. When running trough a debugger it equalse to false.

Comment: I never said page["PropName"] == page.Property["PropName"], quite the opposite) (watch the last .value :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly. But...

I always use page["PropName"] which I know works with "Fetch data from" and "Dynamic properties" and when you have a writable page it also works for setting a value.

Judging by code I've seen from multiple partners and at EPiServer courses it's the most common way too.

You can look at the implementation here and find out exactly:
http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/T_EPiServer_Core_PageData.htm

Answer (score 0):

As Bjorn said:

**CurrentPage["PropertyName"]** is the same as **CurrentPage.Property["PropertyName"].Value**.